# Moving large datasets in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup

I have just inherited a system running on EC2, running several instances and there are some large data volumes - 2TB+. Any suggestions on best (cheapest + quickest) way to back these up and move to local machines ? I think the files will tar and zip efficiently but still be several 100g. Should I just forget about pulling the data down and build new instances based on ec2 backups.

Answer (score 2):

Stage the data to S3. You can then directly download it or have Amazon send it to you on a physical drive using [AWS Import Export](http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/).

Comment: Brilliant - thanks didnt even know that service existed .... should probably read the website !